# How does Microsoft Visio 2013 decide the location of copy-pasted objects?

Tags: copy-paste, microsoft-visio

In Microsoft Visio 2013, when I copy-paste an object with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd>, the object seems to be pasted in a random location. How does Microsoft Visio 2013 decide the location of copy-pasted objects?

---

I know that using the "paste" option in the context menu results in the object being pasted in the location where the user had right-click to open the context menu:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are aware of the problem users face when attempting copy-paste using Ctrl-V and have been working on writing a better logic for it. A problematic scenario around ctrl-V is that Visio sometimes tries to paste near the last pasted position itself instead of the current view where the user is. Pasting by using Context menu works fine, as rightly pointed out by you.  You can expect to see a better and more intuitive experience around copy-paste by using Ctrl-V in a few months' time. 
Thanks,
Shakun Grover,
Program Manager - Visio